# How to render partial Page in ASP.Net mvc3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my ASP.net MVC3 Razor project .I have to implement partial Page inside a normal view page ,but enable only after the action calls.But both files are referencing a single view model.
How to use partial page inside a View page.

Controller Code for Partial Page

```
//View Customer Data Detailed
public ActionResult DetailedData(int CusId)
{
    var data = from c in cus.CusModelData
                where c.CusId == CusId
                select c;
    return View(data.ToList());

}
```

View Code

```
<td>
    @* @Html.ActionLink("Edi", "Edit", new { id = item.CusId }) |*@
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "DetailedData", new { CusId = item.CusId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCustomer", new { CusId = item.CusId })
</td>
```

Controller Code for View Page

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewCutomerData(string Name)
{
    var data = from c in cus.CusModelData
                where c.Name.Contains(Name)
                select c;

    return View(data.ToList());
}
```

Right now i am using like this inside view page

> ## View Customer Data Details
>
> @(Html.Partial("DetailedData")

But again it displaying the table data in the View page .But i want to display it only after  the "Details" Link is clicked.

[image: Screenshot explain waht i am expecting to do]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with ajax call after link click something like:

1. User clicks on link
2. The ajax call is executed:

   ```
   .get("/Details/DetailedData",{"CusId" : requestedId}, function (data) {
       $("#your-detail-container").html(data);
   });
   ```

This line:

```
$("#your-detail-container").html(data);
```

will fill your details container with the view (html).

Would be better if DetailedData action would return PartialView, not the View something like:

```
public ActionResult DetailedData(int CusId)
{
    var data = from c in cus.CusModelData
            where c.CusId == CusId
            select c;

    return PartialView(data.ToList());
}
```

**In answer to your comments:**

I suggest to use

```
@Ajax.ActionLink
```

instead

```
@Html.ActionLink
```

Or just use anchor tag . 
Replace

```
@(Html.Partial("DetailedData")) with <div id="detailed-data-container"></div>
```

and fill this container with get response like this:

```
$(document).on("click",".detailsLink", function () {
        .get("/Details/DetailedData",{"CusId" : requestedId}, function (data) {
            $("#detailed-data-container").html(data);
        });
 });
```

Comment: hello is this correct     @Html.ActionLink("Details", "DetailedData", null, new { CusId = item.CusId }, new { @class = "detailsLink" })         <div id="detailsLink">
               <h1>View Customer Data Details</h1>
                  @(Html.Partial("DetailedData"))     
                  </div>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.detailsLink').click(function () {
            $('#Details').load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>